# Numbering every third row in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am building a list of proofreading corrections in which the first row identifies the page, paragraph and line number for correction
The second row identifies the OLD (existing sentence)
The third row identifies the NEW (suggested change)

I need to number the first row in the first cell and then every third row on down to automatically add one number such as:  1), 2), 3), etc.

Can anyone help me with the formula to do that. Spreadsheets are not my strong suit.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a formula? It looks like if you type "1" in cell A1, select three cells (A1-A3), then drag the autofill handle (where the cursor turns to a `+` sign) on the bottom-right of the selection down it will do what you want. Worked for me in LibreOffice at least which I think should be pretty similar.

Comment: Yes of course baochan the perfect solution. Just shows how rusty I am with spreadsheets. Knew them inside and out 30 years ago. Thanks